# Can a company keep your phone number when you quit if you ported it to the company plan from a personal line originally?

Tags: phone

I recently quit my job and requested that the company port my number to my new provider. The number was originally ported into the company plan from my personal line several years ago. They are refusing to allow me to port my number back out to my new personal plan.

Is this legal? Do you forfeit ownership of the number once you port it to the company account?

Comment: Who was paying the fees? You or the company?

Comment: Yes, the company paid the bill. It was transferred into their account.

Comment: It would depend on the agreement you signed when you ported the number and possibly on the laws of the country where you live and work.

Comment: This is why you keep these things separate.

Comment: You don't "own" your number BTW

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Many companies will let you transfer the number back out, but if you transfer it to a company plan, then it's their number.

Comment: yes, easier to get a new number if they refuse, nothing else you can do

Comment: @Kilisi, yes. My old job gave me a company phone, but I didn't port my number - I just got a new number and still kept my personal phone. It adds some cost because you have to keep paying for the personal phone, but the plus side is that you can keep your #.

Comment: It doesn't add any cost unless you have to pay for the company phone. If the company pays for the company phone then your cost remains the same. You're paying for your phone just as you always did, there's no additional cost to you.

Comment: @joeqwerty, yes, that's what I meant. It adds cost compared to the OP's scenario of only having a company phone and no personal phone.

Comment: @joeqerty Best case would have been to move your old number to a pay-as-you go type sim (and then not use it and therefore not add cost) and use a new number on the company plan. Then when you leave you can use your old personal number - but I guess OPs aim was to not have to ever need to learn a new number (which I totally get because I've had the same one for 10 years now). I guess the other option is seeing if the company will reimburse your contract monthly instead - but I doubt they would because they probably have a good deal with the phone company

Comment: I think next time I might port my personal number to Google Voice so I can use it on the new company phone at the same time.

Comment: It all depends on location and specific company policies. Where I worked before, if it was a company phone you couldn't port the number, but if it was BYOD (in which you choose the device and the plan and the company gives you extra money in the check) you could port the number out. Where I work now, even BYOD you're not allowed to port out. You may take the device (because it is yours) but not the number