# Should I keep a separate cell phone for work vs personal?

Tags: phone

I already use the work profile on my personal phone to get work emails and messages.  But there's also a new option where my company will fully pay for a phone and the associated plan.  Should I start keeping 2 phones, getting a new company phone and making the other one fully personal? My major concerns are with company having access to my personal texts and email (it's not prohibited).  Can they really monitor my personal Google accounts even though I'm using the separate work profile in Android?

Comment: What's the notice period where you work, and how annoying would it be to inform all your personal contacts of a change of phone number if you were suddenly fired?

Comment: You should also take a look at dual sim phones.

Comment: Looking into dual sim.  Will that separate out the apps and access, or just the phone number? I don't mind having a single phone number for both work and personal.  It's just the apps and data I'm worried about.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question as to whether they can access your personal apps is a technology one, not one about the workplace itself.

Comment: @John, If you share the same phone number, then they may have a legal claim over your personal phone number once you stop working for them. Do you really want that? Also, that means they could potentially access your texts and have access to your call history. I know someone who tracks his kids that way since he pays for their phone bill. He has the cell phone carrier automatically log all texts and all the call metadata of his kids.

Comment: Taxation, and phone being locked down by your employer are reasons for having separate phones.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen yes, and here I think it's quite dodgy for an employee to claim the full cost as an expense when it's likely to be mainly used for personal stuff.

Comment: @ChrisH Well, that depends on local regulation. That may be perfectly fine.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Yeah they can also take OP's car's license plate because OP used it during commute for work and thus is now legally owned by OP's employer... that's just as bullshit as saying your personal phone number becomes company property once you use it for work related calls.

Comment: "Should"? There isn't really a should. It's preference

Comment: @GACy20, Ok, you've got me. I used the wrong word. My point is. You need to be careful not to transfer the phone bill to the employer's. Also, you need to be careful about anything you've signed (including your contract, your employee manual, etc). And if you have 2FA SMS authentication turned on for your cell phone account, you need to make sure you never give them real-time access to your texts. Please review this previous question: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/181817/14577 (in my opinion, sharing phone number is just too much trouble, it's just simpler to keep things separate).

Comment: Because there are also other issues to consider. What happens when your phone rings when you're off the clock? Or what happens if your employer phone records/SMS are subpoena'd? Or what happens when you get a new job and you still receive calls about your previous job? Or what happens when IT wants to install a new MDM app on your phone? Do you really want to become a security expert about phones? Or isn't it just simpler to keep your work phone and phone number separate from your personal phone and personal phone number?

Comment: See also: [can a company keep your phone number when you quit...](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/146454/105308). While different in particulars it points out non technical  hazards of using private numbers for work purposes.

Comment: I'm leaning towards getting the company phone and number (fully paid by company), and moving my personal number to a cheaper plan so it's not so expensive.  Company has a listed policy that they would not review personal data, emails, and texts on the company phone.  But I'm not sure how much I trust that.  I'm sure they're not sitting there watching all their employees all day, but if they have a reason to review an employee, they probably will go thru everything.

Comment: Yes. Hard stop.

Answer (score 76):

It's always a good idea to have a dedicated work phone and keep your personal life separate. Even more so if the company pays for it.

Whether or not the company can access anything personal makes no difference. It lessens your expenses and is more professional.

Comment: Currently the company is giving me a stipend where I can expense my cellphone monthly fee, so if I go with 2 phones I would have to pay for my current personal plan.  If I keep the personal and work phone as one, the company will be paying for both.

Comment: Have you considered that they may not be impressed with your monthly billing amount?

Comment: A major reason for separate phones is when you separate from the company. I know someone who owned the company and when he sold it, the contract had to include how his phone was handled in the sale. Other people have had companies demand their phone or demand that they wipe their phone even though the company had not paid for it.

Comment: Many people in my company are given company phones. The rest of us have the "privilege" of installing the company VPN & software on our personal phones. I did this for a while, then got very uncomfortable with the company even _potentially_ having access to my phone or making any demands on it if/when I terminate or just because they suspect something, so I uninstalled everything. I'm still a bit uncomfortable that something remains. I figure if I'm not "important" enough for them to give me a phone (or even a business card), I'm not important enough for them to have _any_ access to my phone.

Comment: That's a long way of saying "take the company phone"!

Comment: It's also possible that if your company gets sued, and you have been using your personal phone for business, that **all** your personal phone records and info get subpoenaed. Which would mean both the work data and your personal info gets sent to the attorneys.

Answer (score 42):

If given a choice:

- two phones: one paid for by work; and one paid for by me
- One phone that I use for work and for personal use.

I will always choose two phones. Therefore work is responsible for the work phone. They pay for it, they can dictate applications, they can wipe it. They can see all the texts, and downloads. Also when you leave you return the phone to them and never have to worry about people from your old job contacting you.

Yes some of this can be done with two profiles, but that work profile is still taking up storage, ram, and CPU cycles while running in the background.

Even if the software always keeps the data separate, the company profile and requirements will be impacting your phone.

Comment: That's a tough choice for me, since keeping two phones means I would have to now pay for my personal line (I can expense that now).  Also company will pay for a new phone which means the work phone (which I use only for work emails and messages) will be the "good" phone.

Comment: @John: Your own line can be had for $15/mo with a decent prepaid MVNO carrier. Yes plenty of people pay $100/mo or so for whatever contracts AT&T or Verizon are marketing to you with "subsidized" (when you don't count the ridiculous line price) new phones every couple years, but there's no good reason to do that.

Comment: Your employer presumably has the phone number you used to apply for the job somewhere in their HR files; if they really want to bug you after you leave they presumably could still do so via that number.

Comment: @John don't assume the work phone will be good or even better than the one you already have, they may buy the cheapest phone that allows you to receive emails and messages.

Comment: Unless you know for certain, @John, that it will be a "good" phone, I wouldn't count on it. My current employer hands out the oldest iPhones they can still get their hands on. Many people _currently_ have iPhone 4s as their company phones. I guess that could be considered "good", but it's certainly not "current".

Comment: "[T]hey can wipe it." There's a fair chance that, in order to use work e-mail on your private phone, you've given your work permissions that include the ability to remotely wipe your phone. _All of it,_ including your private files / apps / messages.

Answer (score 33):

Lots of good answers, but a major point that hasn't been raised is  you can switch a Company phone off(*) if you are on holiday, during the weekend, or even just you've finished for the day. Enforcing that downtime is a really good idea and my main reason for having two phones.

(*) Assuming you're not on call or otherwise contractually obliged to be available.

Comment: I agree about being able to switch off when needed.  I'm also worried about not being able to receive notifications when needed.  With two phones I would have to keep track of both phones.. keeping it charged, and remembering to take it with me when I'm out, etc.

Comment: Note though that quality email apps will allow you to set notifications off for certain hours, so if it's mainly email it's not a problem.  If that's not an option, just get the 2nd handset.  No monthly bill is worth the intrusion into your downtime

Comment: With a double SIM you can also turn off one SIM

Comment: The reverse it's also valid. I have Whatsapp and Skype on personal phone and also on the company phone, because I use them to contact vendors. So I could easily forget about the Whatsapp on personal phone during work hours, but if a vendor answers me on the work phone it's some work related stuff.

Comment: Having two separate phones is a physical tool that can help you manage the work/life balance. It forces you to categorize your actions and contacts and can help you @John and others around you identify when you are on work time or personal time. If you take a lot of work calls out of the office and have a young family, the presence or absence of the work phone in certain situations sends a profound message to the rest of the family.

Comment: You could temporarily block work numbers on any phone, or just use caller ID. Even if you maintain 2 separate phones, it's still possible that work will have your personal phone number (e.g. if you gave it when you applied for the job, or for emergencies, or if you have a friend in the office). So it's really a matter of the convenience of turning off your work phone vs having to explicitly block numbers.

Answer (score 19):

I wanted to throw one more answer in here as former administrator of company provided cell phones.  Of course, this is a very subjective topic as one company may want to see everything on a company phone while other companies simply provide them as perks and could care less what users do on them.

Myself?  I jumped on the opportunity to have my company pay for my cell phone - it was one less bill for me.  I've had to have this discussion with users before as to what we see when we "manage" devices - and the honest answer is not much. I've worked through a few MDM applications, but the most personal thing I could see would be what apps were installed.  Other than that, I couldn't read messages, couldn't see call history, couldn't go through the photos or anything like that.  I could however remotely wipe the device in its entirety.

The power to remotely wipe a device comes directly from email access, if you add company email to a phone they can wipe it remotely to protect their intellectual property.  This is actually a product of Exchange - I can count on one hand the amount of times I've been asked to do this.  This power could also come from an MDM application itself as they are usually agent based.  The "work folders" Android configuration essentially fences off your work/personal life - Apple doesn't really have a similar feature but it was getting there.

Last point, and again a semi-anecdotal one, is nobody cares what you do on your phone as long as you're not breaking the law with it.  I never spent my days going through the huge list of devices to see who had what apps installed - besides not caring it offered no real value to me.  Modern MDM solutions, like Intune, are getting so powerful that it's getting even easier to segment the work and personal sides of devices.

So long story short, take the free phone and use it as both your work/personal.  Most IT professionals don't care what you do on the device as long as you're not downloading viruses or running a criminal empire from it.

*Edited for clarity

Comment: Great points.  I already have the work email on my current personal phone, so they can wipe it anytime. Do you know with Android work profile, if they do wipe, does it wipe the whole phone or just the work profile?

Comment: *The power to remotely wipe a device comes directly from email access* And that's why I won't install Outlook on my personal phone.  Bluemail talks to Exchange Server as well and doesn't give the email admin people rights over the phone.   (Academia, so lines between work and personal can get a little more blurry than in the corporate world)

Comment: For what it's worth, there's already no protection against the phone being stolen, spontaneously combusting, etc so the possibility of remote wipe isn't that much of additional risk. If there's something you don't want to lose on the phone, keep backups.

Comment: @ojs It's not as much "losing something on the phone" but rather losing something at a poorly timed moment. A decade ago I unexpectedly had my first smartphone wiped 6 months after leaving a temp job while on vacation abroad (I don't know why they didn't wipe it earlier). If this were to happen again with my current phone, it would wipe off 4 different authenticator apps: Microsoft, Google, Google Authenticator and Battle.net. Most of those would be a severe hassle to recover access to, especially abroad with no access to backups.

Comment: I'm confused by this answer. You go into great depth about how little access you had to a person's phone beyond the ability to wipe it, hinting at the fact that using one phone for both work & personal is just fine, then say "take the free phone", indicating using separate phones. Can you either clarify my confusion or reconcile the two different positions suggested here?

Comment: @FreeMan I understand how my wording could come off as confusing - when I say take the free phone I'm implying that only one phone is needed.  So let the company eat your phone bill and you're free to use the work phone as your personal (within reason of course).

Comment: @John If I remember correctly it's only the Android Work profile that gets wiped - for Apple devices is was the whole thing.  It's been a few years since I've administered those kinds of devices so it probably has gotten smoother.  The technology for MDM is one of the fastest changing out there.

Comment: That makes more sense, @MikeWRX. You may want to edit to clarify that.

Comment: Interesting and informative answer

Comment: Most IT staff are decent people who don't intrude into colleagues' personal life. But there's the risk of the incompetent IT staff, who accidentally wipe your phone, and the malicious - particularly if you're a woman you may worry about someone getting obsessed and stalkery or jealous. Just because something isn't normally visible, doesn't mean it's inaccessible. It's a question of weighing risks and benefits, and will depend on your opinion of the IT dept where you work.

Comment: Finally, a well-informed answer. I did a bunch of research on MDM for iPhone management, and can confirm that the company cannot access your personal data. They can see info about the phone,  fully control company apps installed through their portal app, and a list of apps you have installed. They can also enforce restrictions like no iCloud access and install a Web filter.  The restrictions might be a deal breaker for some, inconsequential for others.

Answer (score 12):

> My major concerns are with company having access to my personal texts and email (it's not prohibited). Can they really monitor my personal Google accounts even though I'm using the separate work profile in Android?

If you allow your company to install anything on your personal phone, you need to assume that they now have total control over your phone and can see and/or do anything to anything on your phone.

If you are comfortable with this arrangement then you can continue using your personal phone for work, otherwise I would opt for a company provided phone.

Comment: I wouldn't quite go that far - the app separation which is enforced by both Android and iOS means that just installing an app can't give them control over anything else (yes, I am assuming my employer's app does not exploit holes in the OS's security model). Agreed entirely with this answer though if you install any MDM software.

Comment: @PhilipKendall That's not completely true.  I used to work for a company that used MS Outlook.  I wished to use Outlook on my phone, so I installed it but when I went to configure for my company's settings, it said I had to grant permissions to wipe the entire phone if the company deemed it necessary from their side.  Great big NOPE.

Comment: @XavierJ An app _cannot_ do that without MDM being installed; Outlook can be configured so that it won't do anything unless the appropriate MDM granting that permission is installed though.

Comment: It may not be *technically* true  that a company has total control over your phone but it's a fair assumption to make!

Comment: @PhilipKendall it comes to exactly the same thing - to use corporate outlook on your phone you have to grant unreasonable permissions over your personal stuff.  It doesn't really matter whether granting the permissions leads to installing mysteriously-named (I had to look it up when I refused the same thing, and I was looking out for it) software in an extra step - no remote wipe permissions  = no email.

Answer (score 8):

It's a personal choice, in the end.

I have kept a seperate private phone for around 20 years now (despite company phones provided during most of those years), and haven't regretted it. Yes, it costs me extra, yes there is some inconvenience in carrying around 2 phones, but:

- I always know if an incoming call is a work or a private call
- I can switch off and put away my work phone on weekends
- I go to holidays and leave my work phone at home
- I keep my private phone and phone number when I switch jobs
- I can pick whatever phone I want, not what company policy allows

For me, these advantages are more than worth it. But as I said, for someone else, they may not.

Comment: This. 100% agree exept for extra cost. (no need to pay for a company phone, they pay for it. And one needs a personal phone these day, so that already is a sunk cost).

Comment: @Hennes many people around me have a company phone with permission to use it for private purposes, and they don't own a private phone. For them, having a seperate private phone would be an extra cost.

Comment: Technically though - and even if the monetary effect is the same - is it an extra cost or missed savings? Anyway I agree with this answer most, it's good to go out of the house and not having to worry about work-related matters suddenly popping up in your freetime. In my perspective, most of the benefits are on the psychological side of not being available all the time and actually having control about when you can be bothered with work. Also there is always the risk of accidentally calling a person (pocket-call) which can be way more awkward if it's a business contact than a personal one.

Comment: Do you ensure nobody at your work has your personal phone number? Did you use that phone number when you applied for the job, do you not give prospective employers your phone number, or do you change your number regularly? Do you let any colleagues contact you out of work? Really, it depends on whether your employer and colleagues are assholes, not on how many phones you have.

Comment: @StuartF the person who brought me into that company has my personal phone number, nobody else.

Comment: How do you carry 2 phones? I'm often on-call so the work phone would have to be with me 24/7 during that time. I carry my personal phone in my front pants pocket, which it consumes. My other front pocket is for wallet, keys, etc. back pockets aren't used.

Comment: @majorgear I'm not on-call anymore and haven't been for many years. I sometimes bring my work phone if there's a crucial project or something, but it's not common.

Answer (score 4):

I would hate to have to carry two phones. I'd rather use my private phone for a bit of work than having a second phone.

On the other hand, I use it very little for work. There is a 2FA app running on it (so I do something on my works computer and I have to press a button on my phone). And some things are connected through 2FA to my phone number. No problem either. My phone is not set up to read company email, or slack, that's what the computer is for. Some people have my private phone number, and my second private email address, for emergencies. (And things like messages from payroll *should* go to my private phone IMO).

It really depends on usage. If people get your private phone number who don't know the difference between "emergency" and "not emergency", then the company has to pay for a second phone. And if it's not obvious: No control over my phone will be given to the company. Ever.

Answer (score 3):

Carrying around two phones is indeed a bit more of a hassle, but there are a lot of benefits for doing so:

- You can use whatever type/model phone you want and upgrade it whenever you want. You're not limited to a platform that's compatible with your company's systems.
- No risk of your company's IT department remotely wiping your personal data off of your phone.
- Your company can't access your call logs, email, and other personal communications, so you can interview for new jobs without alerting your current employer.
- Most of the time, accessing work systems on your phone requires you to authorize your employer to run a piece of software that has administrator rights over your device.  Such a program can technically access anything on the device, regardless of profiles.  It's a creepy overreach, and it can prevent you from doing things like rooting your phone, installing certain security software, etc.  You should be in full control of your own device, don't give your IT department a backdoor into your system.
- Separate phones make it significantly easier to protect confidential information.  Having no company information on your personal device means that you can use whatever apps you want, even apps like social media that harvest your contact list (including any confidential information stored there).  Similarly, you can have your personal device back up all your info to the cloud without risk of company information getting copied along with it.  Profiles are supposed to protect against a lot of this but they aren't perfect.  Assume any software on your phone will have access to *all* of your phone's contents.
- While at work, you can put your personal device on vibrate and leave the ringer on for your work phone.  While not at work, vice versa.
- Vacations become a lot more restful when coworkers know you leave your work phone in your desk when you go on vacation.  They try to call you, can hear your desk ringing, and it reinforces the point that you're off the clock.  Or, you can leave your phone with a coworker and they can seamlessly handle any customer calls while you're gone.
- Your personal and work phones can be on completely separate carriers/networks.  If you get stuck in a dead spot, you can always use the other phone in a pinch.  Very useful for people who work at customer sites and not in the same office every day.
- Stuck on an annoying call that you can't get out of? "Hey, my work phone is ringing, I have to go".  My sister uses that one every time I call her.
- Doing your taxes gets simpler.  You no longer have to figure out what you paid that's a work-related expense, what taxes you have to pay on your company's phone plan reimbursement, etc.  Separate devices for separate purposes will eliminate all of that.
- If you travel internationally for work, your company can pay for the more expensive plan that includes international access.  Even if your company currently pays for your phone plan, upgrading plans often requires a long-term contract.  If you leave the company, you're now stuck paying out the rest of that expensive international plan yourself.
- Have small kids?  You can let them use your personal phone to watch a video or play a game without worrying that they'll accidentally delete those important emails that you really need.
- A separate work phone makes it a lot harder to forget what profile you're currently using and accidentally send that embarrassing tweet from the company's official account.
- Your personal email and text messages contain lots of information that most locales consider "sensitive" and protected: medical information, family details, etc.  Using a single phone often means this information will be exposed to your employer.  Even if it's technically illegal for them to discriminate against you based on that information, don't even give them the temptation to do so.  Keep your work and personal stuff isolated on separate devices.
- Having a separate work phone *number* is enough of a benefit in and of itself:

  - Only give your personal number out to the coworkers that you really like.  When you leave the company, those annoying coworkers can't contact you.
  - Some office phone systems can link your work number to both your mobile and your desk phone.  When you're in the office, that number rings your desk phone.  When you're out of the office, it rings your work mobile.  That can't typically be done with a personal number.
  - After you switch jobs, your old phone/number can be assigned to another team member.  This makes transitions easier.  Your customers will call the same number but instead of getting you, they'll get the new person in charge of the account.  Much easier than hoping everyone updates their records and doesn't have an old business card laying around somewhere.
  - Similarly, you won't have customers calling you after you leave the company.  Not only is that annoying, it can potentially have legal consequences.  If you leave to work for a competitor, having old clients call you (even unknowingly) could be interpreted as trying to poach customers.  Many contracts and non-compete agreements specifically prohibit this but even when they don't, it's considered unethical in many places.  Leaving the old number behind means you walk away clean and it's hard to accuse you of doing anything improper.
  - Many apps and services use text messages for two-factor authentication.  TFA codes for personal use shouldn't be sent to a number that the company controls, since you can't predict or control who else can see those codes.

I don't have a separate mobile phone for work (I don't use my phone for work at all), but I know a lot of people that do.  Exactly zero of them regret it.  Several of them do it even though they have to pay for the work phone themselves.  It takes a few weeks to get accustomed to carrying around two phones, but it's completely worth it.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, it's a personal decision. There are trade-offs either way.

Without knowing your specific set-up it's difficult to know what the balance is, but to answer the specific question you are asking it is unlikely that your company can access your personal data - with a few caveats.

Potentially a detailed question could be more fully answered in the [Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=work%20profile) or [Security StackExchanges](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/246377/android-work-profile-permissions), but a common way for companies to implement this is to use [Google Workspaces](https://workspace.google.com/) on an Android phone which sets up a [Work Profile](https://support.google.com/work/android/answer/6191949?hl=en). These have access to [specific subset](https://support.google.com/work/android/answer/7502354#zippy=%2Ci-own-my-device) of data on your personal phone, which in brief, is meta-data about your phone. You also have [the option to turn off this work profile including on a schedule](https://support.google.com/work/android/answer/7029561?hl=en) if you don't want to be disturbed by work at certain times, or increasing your privacy during more sensitive times such as medical appointments.

As long as your phone is kept patched with the latest security updates this is all your company could see.

There may however be more invasive software that you do not want that your company may enforce on to your phone which you may want to investigate in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

No one I know (software consulting business) has 2 phones except those at annoying companies who don't allow personal devices.  The problem with 2 phones is that no one who knows you from work will be able to find you again after you leave.  If you work in an industry where people know each other, there is a huge value in keeping the same phone number over time.

The problem with people knowing everything about you is Google and Apple, not your company.  They can't see your google email by allowing an office account on the phone.

Carry 2 phones if you want, but I don't see the value.

Comment: "The problem with 2 phones is that no one who knows you from work will be able to find you again after you leave" - that's also a problem if your company decides to keep your phone number when you leave because they decide it's their asset.

Comment: +1 @LaconicDroid, wanting to keep in touch with people after you leave the Company is a reason to have 2 phones, you're making a huge gamble otherwise.

Comment: @LaconicDroid - if the company pays the monthly bill and takes over responsibility for maintaining the account, perhaps; in any other case it's not realistic to see how the company could make any sort of valid legal case for expropriating the number from the OP's control and ownership. if you have concrete examples of this happening I'd love to read them as my company contacts me and sends me business info and emergency alerts on my 'phone all the time (on a number I registered and have been paying for since 1993) and if there was any possibility they could seize it, I want to know.

Comment: What you're saying then, is that it's impossible for you to swap personal contact info with your coworkers while you're still employed? Heck, I have both work & personal cell phone _and_ email addresses of many of my coworkers right now. Since I'm not "important" enough to merit a work-issued phone (it's much cheaper for them to expect me to use mine for work purposes), many of my coworkers have my personal cell number. If I, or any of them, leave the company, they'll still have my personal number which hasn't changed in 27 years.

Comment: @Spratty Phone numbers are technically owned and controlled by the *phone company* (at least in the US) and not the bill payer or the employer.  That makes a lot of things very subtly different, and presents problems that don't exist for normal property. Some companies require you to give them the number as a condition of reimbursing your phone bills.  Others just go to the phone company and request the number ported over to them (and you don't really have recourse if the phone company goes along with it).

Comment: i have worked for 4 different companies and kept the same phone number.  Companies don't want your number, they release it to you.  I  feel like these are worry issues, not actual issues.  The company policy will tell you if they retain ownership of the phone or not; again, it is uncommon in the US to need to carry 2 phones.

Answer (score 1):

Having two phones is usually more inconvenient, as you need to juggle two devices at the same time to access both your personal and your work life.

However this inconvenience can also be a benefit. Having two devices mean that

- It's easier to separate your work from your personal stuff, which can lead to a better work-life balance
- There is no way the company can access your personal phone's content
- Once you leave the company you don't need to worry about what work related stuff might have been left on your personal phone
- Sometimes you can get/buy the company phone when you leave (or the phone gets replaced) which might leave you with a better phone that you can use afterwards or give to your friends and family

Occasionally it can have drawbacks, especially if you need to have both of your phones with you at the same time, for example if you are the on-call support person over the weekend or similar.

You have two decide whether the inconvenience of having two phones is more of a benefit to you or more of a drawback. If you do decide that one phone is easier to handle then however make sure to use whatever tool is available on that phone to separate your personal and work life:

- Never allow yourself to access company resources with your personal phone's personal profile. Use features like Samsung's Secure Folder or Huawei's PrivateSpace to separate your work profile from your personal one. These both add an extra layer of security to access your work profile and make sure that your company can also only access this part of your device
- If the above is not available, Google's Work Profile, or simply setting up a new separate user account on your phone is definitely the minimum. Again these tools will make sure that the company will only be able to access things that are on your work profile, given you make sure nothing of your personal stuff gets mixed with your work stuff
- (If you get a work SIM card as well) make sure you get a dual-SIM phone so you can use both your work and personal SIM cards at the same time. There's no point in having a single device if you need to swap sim cards every time

Answer (score 1):

There is also the hybrid option of having one phone with two subscriptions. Many modern phones support dual SIM (or SIM + eSIM). You still have one device (that you own for example), have your private subscription on one SIM (or eSIM) and get a SIM card from your employer to no have to pay for work related calls. You separate - you just return the SIM card.

What to do with the messages and data in the device is a separate matter.

Answer (score 1):

Big, fat YES, use two phones.

Unless it is your or your mom's business, your employer may turn hostile to you in a hearthbeat. Bad things do happen.

What's more, even if you are on generally good terms with your boss, there will be a whole command chain over yout phone and the safety of its personal content.

Your company sysadmin, HR clerk, your immediate manager and probably some other people can wipe, lock, terminate the cell contract or in some cases browse the contents of your phone even by mistake. Mistakes do happen.

And then, phones do break sometimes. Having some kind of backup that you decide when to use is good.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I have my private and work phone separated mainly due to your existing concern: *with company having access to my personal texts and email*

It depends on jurisdiction, but in a good deal of cases, a work phone would be considered *company property*, and any connection to your personal accounts would be open to them whether they intentionally access it or not.

If you want things kept private - you keep your private stuff on a device that *you* and only *you* have full control over.

The main concern is also the reason why I have separate private/work phones even though they both have the dual SIM feature.

The second reason to use separate phones may be for tax reasons. In my case (Denmark) you'd be charged a tax each month from your pay if you use a work phone privately.

Answer (score 1):

OK, all answers are about having two phones, I will throw mine which is about having only one.

I always have had one phone since 1998 when I got my first one. It has always been a company phone.

This was because:

- Android now has a separate work and personal profile
- I know what the company is having access to
- I live in a country with strong privacy laws
- I work for an ethical company
- I know that if I was leaving, I could get my number with me
- I can change phones to better ones more often

There are plenty of good aspects that are much more compelling than the bad ones.

I need and want to be able to answer work-related calls anytime because if someone calls me it is important.

I will not read company emails on vacation (except if I need to), and I do not get any notification when they arrive.

This is a specific, comfortable situation and I would hate to have to carry two phones.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the responses.  Based on all the answers here, it is pretty clear that this is subjective and an individual choice that depends on so many variables.  The responses here help and educate people like me to make that choice.

I requested for a separate device and a new number, which made the most sense for my situation.  This gives me the option to selectively use the work phone, rather than fully adding work profile to my personal phone.

In my situation, work/life balance is not a concern.  I'm not worried about getting work phone calls outside of business hours.  If anything, in my role I want to get those notifications real time rather than walking into a bigger unfavorable situation on Monday morning.

My company has a written policy that they will not access personal data on the phone.  However, I do know that if they have a reason to suspect anything, they can and will go thru the emails and text messages.  My interpretation is that once I port over my personal number to the company, that becomes company paid property which they can review anytime without notice.  In that case it doesn't restrict them from reviewing personal messages regardless of what that policy says. I don't even think they would need access to my phone to do any of that.

So my plan is to keep two phones. Keep my current personal phone and number, but move to a cheaper plan.  Get the new phone and number from the company, and use that primarily.  My major drawback is that I would have to charge and carry two phones everywhere. What I'm still in the process of researching is whether company can see other personal emails and apps outside of the Android work profile.  If that is safe (I know I should assume company can see everything), I would use the new company phone for apps like navigation and forward my personal calls to the new company number, so then I don't have to carry two phones everywhere.  I still have the option to detach anytime.